# Hook for writing text string after footer scripts

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, footer

I'm looking to insert a string of JavaScript variables AFTER the in_footer enqueued scripts.  When I write the string via the wp_footer hook, they occur before the in_footer scripts.  Is there another hook I can tie into that happens after those enqueued scripts have been written.

Comment: What priorities have you tried on the hook? I think if you just dump the priority out (or maybe put it real high...one of the two, I never remember) it should adjust where it falls in relation to the enqueue.

Comment: Sure, can do! And done!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you change the priority on the hook to `wp_footer` you should be able to shift when it's called in reference to the enqueue functions.

**Example:**

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'my_footer_hook', PHP_INT_MAX);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also the `shutdown` hook that runs last just before `wp_cache_close();`, but you should run the filters only until a priority of 9.

Another option would be to hook with a priority as high as possible for e.g. 9999 into the hook (priority is the 3<sup>rd</sup> arg).